# Oneway sync of Windows folders

Tags: windows, synchronization, directory

I have a folder where I don't want to modify any existing files in.
But I want to be able to add and remove files easily and recognize these files easily.

I thought in something like a SymLink but I want one folder where only the added files are shown and then the source folder with all files.

Is there anything like this? Or do you have a better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found [SyncToy](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15155) from microsoft.
It has an echo mode which does what I wanted.